# how to make new session in after editing .bashrc file

Tags: python, bash, shell

Hi all I am learning python script and trying to write some code.

I have found issue while when i edit ".bashrc" file. After editing `.bashrc` I need to either type `bash` or `source .bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` , and then whatever changes we have done in `.bashrc` file will take effect.
 But once i do `bash` using `os.system` or `subprocess`,  I will comeout from the present working directory and the GUI freezes (new session starts), I will not able to do any kind of operation and I have so much of work after that. Please suggest me the proper guidance to come out from this

In .bashrc file I wants to add new line and then it's the new sandbox. If we wont give "bash " command Its not gonna take effect. Sabdbox will be old one only.

Code Whatever i have tried:

```
   os.chdir("/home") 
   subprocess.call("sed -i 's/export SANDBOX=~\/xxxx/export SANDBOX=~\/yyyy/' .bashrc",shell=True)
   os.system("/bin/bash")
  #os.system("source ~./bashrc")
   os.system("/home/creart")
```

Afetr last two lines pwd is "/home and gui freezes.

Comment: please add code which demonstrates the problem you encounter

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish, what is the purpose of `.bashrc` editing from a Python script.

Comment: So, you want to change an environment variable for a process. Which process?

Comment: @spbnick: Cant say , company related thing.

Comment: @spbnick: how to achive what i mentioned above, please share knowledge if you know.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Make permanent changes to `.bashrc` during some kind of application setup?

Comment: @nammu, It doesn't matter exactly what program that is. It matters more what process it is related to your Python script. Is it the Python script itself that should have its environment variable changed? Is it a program that is started independently, i.e. not from the Python script? Or is it that "/home/creart" program you're starting at the end of your code chunk?

Comment: the first thing that comes to my mind is that you are using double quotes on subprocess and sed (and you are missing one)

Comment: @Patrick it works if i do without GUI

Comment: @ThomasFenzl yes. Creating new sandbox and doin svn checkout to that afterwards add export SANBOX line in .bashrc file , run "bash" command..all I have to do using python for GUI i have used wxpython

Comment: @spbnick yes python itslef changed its environment variable

Comment: @nammu OK, see an addition to my answer for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your program freezes, because in the absence of a command to execute, `bash` starts interactive session and waits for input. Anyway, changes to .bashrc only affect new interactive sessions and thus only programs started from an *interactive* session started after that change will be affected.

If you want to change an environment variable for that "/home/creart" program, you can simply modify the environment variable on invocation, as the string you supply to `os.system` is passed to "/bin/sh" after "-c" option. Like this:

```
os.system("SANDBOX=~/yyyy/ /home/creart")
```

Otherwise, if you want to change an environment variable for your Python script and all processes started from it with preserved environment (`os.system` preserves environment), just modify [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.environ) mapping object. Like this:

```
os.environ["SANDBOX"] = "/home/user/yyyy"
```

Note, that `~` will not get substituted with a home directory in this case.

Comment: Creating new sandbox and doin svn checkout to that afterwards add export SANBOX line in .bashrc file , run "bash" command..all I have to do using python for GUI i have used wxpython

Comment: @nammu I'm sorry, but I can't extract much sense from your comment.

Comment: @nammu could you please explain exactly what your Python script should do?

Comment: It have to automate svn operations like connecting to svn server and do svn update and all..But if new user created( I mean if user wants to create new sandbox and do svn opearation) then its should add new line "export SANDBOX =~/newuser" in .bashrc file.  but afterwards to take affect in shell script we usualy give "bash" after exiting the .bashrc file. when i run "bash" in python its creating problem for me . I am looking for alternative solution or what wrong I am done here.

Comment: @nammu The problem is that you're not fully understanding how environment and shells work. Each program has its own, independent, set of environment variables, or simply "environment", which it can modify. Modifying one program's environment doesn't affect other running programs. When a program starts another program it can define an environment for it. Usually, programs just give their own environment to started programs. Shells put all "exported" variables into environment of started programs. Shells also execute scripts at startup, such as .bashrc, which can set variables and "export" them.

Comment: @nammu Now, considering the above, please tell what exact effect you expect from running "/bin/bash" from your Python script.

Comment: If i create new sandbox and add newly created sandbox name in .bashrc, and save and quit. Now give cd $SANDBOX , it will show old one , if I run command bash in command line , and then if i give cd $SANDBOX then newly created sandbox name can be seen

Comment: @nammu I understand your logic, but it's flawed. You have to understand how environments work and how shells operate them. Read my comment about them above, search the Web for "environment variable" for more, and read basic tutorials on shells. Then try to apply the acquired knowledge to your problem.

Comment: No way to do it in python?

Comment: There is very likely a way to do "it" in Python, whatever "it" is. However, your understanding seems to be insufficient to describe what "it" is. You seem to be confused about what environment variables and processes are and how they relate to each other. Please try to understand that and then ask your question again. Otherwise neither I nor probably anybody else will be able to help you without educating you first.

Comment: More precisely, you seek for a solution of invalid problem, based on incorrect understanding of how things work.